# How to write a taffyDB query using a variable as an attribute title?

Tags: javascript, taffydb

I'm using [taffyDB](http://www.taffydb.com/) to query my javascript objects. I have a database `db()`, where each item in the db has an attribute `Test Field` and an attribute `Test_Field`.

If I want to query all the items in `db()` for which the value of `Test_Field` is "test", the following works:

```
var dbQuery = db({ Test_Field:"test" }).get()
```

However, if I want to query all the items in `db()` for which the value of `Test Field` is "test", I cannot find any query that works. The following are my best attempts.

```
var dbQuery = db({ Test Field:"test" }).get()

var fieldName = "Test Field"
var dbQuery = db({ fieldName:"test" }).get()

var field = {}
field[name] = "Test Field"
var dbQuery = db({ field[name]:"test" }).get()
```

I want to grab the items where `Test Field` is `"test"` Any ideas how to query with a variable name so that I can check an attribute with space in its name like `Test Field`?

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if I am being unclear or if you need anything else from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `db().filter({"Test Field": "test"});`
or
`var obj = {}; obj[fieldName] = "test"; db().filter(obj);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var fieldName = "Test Field"
var dbQuery = db({ fieldName:"test" }).get()
```

The above does not work because the object assigns the value "test" to the key "fieldname" and your object looks like this :

```
{fieldname:"test"}
```

and not

```
{"Test Field":"test"}
```

Try Doing :

```
fieldName = "Test Field";
var field = {};
field[fieldName] = "test";
var dbQuery = db(field).get();
```